# Combine server database and embedded database electron / react application

Tags: reactjs, database, react-redux, electron

I'm developing an electron application with react and I would like to combine data from an embedded database and server database. Some data on the server has permissions and both database will have the same schema. I saw rxdb but I'm not sure I can achieve that.

Do you have any recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think rxdb will work for your approach.
You can store data locally and also replicate data from the server to the client.
If you want to do queries over the full data-set, you can replicate the local store and the server-store into a local in-memory collection from rxdb and run queries there.

DISCLAIMER: I'm the author of rxdb

Comment: I will know for a future project that I can do that. But for this project, we can't install a CouchDB server for the remote database so I will find another way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can also replicate with a graphql-endpoint, if you do not want to use couchdb on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to replicate the remote server locally to provide faster response times and offline capabilities.  I further assume that because your question includes "react" you're looking at how to replicate in the browser.

This is conceptually possible, but labor intensive.  You'll wind up using a suite of APIs to access remote values, and database calls to some kind of [web-based local storage](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage).

You could conceptually merge the local storage database with the remote database, but I have found when I have done this it's often easer to consider a store-and-forward approach.  YMMV.

I would then create an SDK in my application that would route between the local and remote storage, so that the front-end didn't have to worry about the complexity of how the data were stored, managed, merged or what have you.

Good luck!

Comment: No I don’t want to replicate ,the local data will be different from the server. For exemple let’s say I have client stored locally for the user and « general » client stored on the server. I want to merge visually both data.